# in app purchase is not working properly. It gives "Can not connect to itunes"

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

When performing in app purchase, it shows "can not connect to itunes". i.e it goes to "fail transaction method" and after few seconds it goes to "complete transaction method". I want to handle both the case separately. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "it shows" and "it goes"? What's "it"? Please provide details, and preferably some code also.

Comment: Either provide code or please check the complete implementation of [in app purchase here][1]


  [1]: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: For in app when I click on Buy button, transaction's delegate methods will be called (like transaction failed, transaction complete, transaction restored etc). In my case first transaction failed method is getting called. And there I am displaying error description which gives "can not connect to itunes". And after few second "complete transaction" delegate method is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem, that is displayed in the iPhone simulators.
Try testing the application on a device. I am pretty sure, the problem will not be present for InApp purchases.

Comment: Did you face same problem for in app?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I still do. Its just a simulator problem, it works fine on device.

Comment: Well I will test in device. Thank you.